# Regex remove after 2nd match only

Tags: jquery, regex

I'm trying to use jquery.replace() regex expression for the following :

I have song titles, some contain 2 hyphens ( - ) as an example :

```
Artist name - song title
Artist name - song title - album here
```

Im trying to remove everything after the 2nd -

What i've tried is the following :

```
var trimmedSong = (songTitle).replace(/\-[^-]*$/g, "");
```

where songTitle is the string

But what happens is i get the following output :

```
Artist name
Artist name - song title
```

So whilst its working ok on the 2nd - its actually not working if there is only 1 -, any ideas or suggestions as to where ive gone wrong?

Many thanks
Eddy

Comment: `.replace(/^(.*? - .*?) - .*/, '$1')`? See https://regex101.com/r/UTA1sy/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
var trimmedSong = (songTitle).replace(/(-[^-]*) -.*/, '$1');
```

Explanation:

- `(-[^-]*)` - capture group 1 that matches a dash and anything that is not a dash
- `-.*` - a space, dash and anything else
- in replacement, use capture group 1
- note that the regex fails and does nothing if there are not two dashes

You could also use a positive lookbehind, but that is not supported by all browsers

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```js
const texts = ['Artist name - song title','Artist name - song title - album here'];
const rx = /^(.*? - .*?) - .*/;
for (const s of texts) {
  console.log(s, '=>', s.replace(rx, '$1'));
}
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NlI2zj/1).

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `(.*? - .*?)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as few as possible, space, `-`, space, any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `-`  - space, `-`, space
- `.*` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible.

The replacement is the backreference to Group 1 value.

Answer (score 0):

You could try with:

```js
var trimmedSong = (songTitle).replace(songtitle.match(/\- .* (- .*)/)[1], "").trim();
```